# Is it possible to shutdown linux kernel and resume in Real Mode?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, boot, bios, real-mode

Let's say I'd like to start a small linux distro before my ordinary operating system start.

1. BIOS load MBR and execute MBR.
2. MBR locates the active partition which is my linux partition.
3. Linux start and I perform what I need to do.
4. Linux shut down and I switch to Real Mode again.
5. The original partition boot sector is loaded and my ordinary OS start.

AFAIK, step 4 will be the difficult task, restore the state on all devices prior to linux, will INT13h be functional? Do I need to restore the Interrupt Vector Table? To mention a few.

Has this been done in any existing project perhaps?

Comment: If your intention is to create Linux-based bootloader that would be more capable than something like GRUB, this is really hard. I started such a project, but never quite finished it. However, this definitely is possible, see Splashtop.

Comment: This really isn't (IMHO) programming related. However, IIRC, once an x86 or compatible processor is in protected mode, you can't switch back to real mode without a reset.

Comment: Well, for me it's programming related since I actually intend to try this, hence the question.
And yes,you can switch back to real mode again (Intel Software Manual 3 chapter 9).

Comment: @Zifre: out of curiosity, where did you got stuck? Thanks for the tip regarding Splashtop, seems like an interesting product.

Comment: I got stuck at this part (returning to real mode and clearing all device state). When I wanted to boot another Linux based OS it worked fine with kexec, but I needed it to also support Windows. I eventually did get something that worked on my PC, but it often didn't work on other PCs (clearing device state is really hard). Returning to real mode definitely is possible, I don't remember how I did it though, and I don't have the code with me right now.

Comment: Also, this is one of those questions that might be better at a place like OSDev (not many people here know about this type of stuff). I'm pretty sure there are some forum topics about returning to real mode that you could look at.

Comment: @Harper, that only applied on the 286. Support for returning to real mode was added on the 80386. There were also hacky workarounds involving triggering a triple fault and using various BIOS support for the 80286 as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linux does not normally support this, particularly since it reinitializes hardware in a way that the BIOS and DOS programs may not expect. However, there is some infrastructure to switch back to real mode in specific cases - particularly, for a reboot (see machine_real_restart in arch/x86/kernel/reboot.c) - and has code to reinitialize hardware for kexec or suspend. I suspect you might be able to do something with a combination of these - but I don't know if the result will truly match what DOS or Windows would expect to see on reboot.

A much easier plan would be to use a chainloading bootloader that can be set to boot in a particular configuration once, like [GRUB](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#Booting-fallback-systems). You could invoke grub-set-default, then reboot. When GRUB comes up, it would then pass control off to Windows. By then setting the fallback OS to the Linux partition, control would return to Linux on the next boot.

Yet another option may be to use [Coreboot](http://www.coreboot.org/SeaBIOS), but I'm not sure if this is production-ready for booting windows yet.

Answer (score 3):

i haven't tried this so I don't know if it would work, but here goes:

There is an option in the header of a bzImage format kernel file that specifies the address of real mode code to execute before the protected mode code starts.  You could create a minimal bzImage-compliant file which has no actual kernel, but which has real mode code to load your MBR using INT 0x13 to 0x7c00 and jmp into it like the BIOS does.

If you use kexec to load the bzImage using the "-t bzImage-x86 --real-mode" options, it should reset the PE bit in CR0 to drop to realmode (as bdonlan above mentioned) and execute the code pointed to by the bzImage header option.

The bzImage header option is called realmode_swtch and is documented in /usr/src/linux/Documentation/x86/boot.txt , the header format code is in /usr/src/linux/arch/x86/boot/header.S

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into [kexec](http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Kexec)?